# SQL tables joined with max

Tags: sql, asp.net, join, max

I'm working with two tables.  I have a full list of groups in table A, and a list of each group member that has been reviewed in table B.  So table B is a log of all review records for those members for each group.

```
select a.Group_Name, Max(b.Request_Review_Date)
From GroupTable a
Left Outer Join GroupReviews b ON a.Group_Name = b.Group_Name
Group By a.Group_Name
```

What I am trying to return is the full list of groups from table A, and find the latest review date from table B for each of those groups.

I have researched and tried all or most of the inner & outer joins, apply methods....but its just not giving me the results.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Or am I having to bring back two result sets and compare in my ASP code-behind?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Your query looks correct. What is wrong with the result?

Comment: I am getting the full list of groups, however, I am not returning the latest review date for each.  That column is NULL

Comment: Are you sure you're joining on the right column? Can you confirm it by running the query without the `GROUP BY` clause, using `SELECT *`, and confirm that you are getting the appropriate records from both tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a CTE then join back to it

```
   WITH Recent AS
  (

  select group_name, max(Request_Review_Date) AS 'MaxReviewDate'
  from GroupReviews
  group by  group_name


  )
    select a.group_name, MaxReviewDate
    from GroupTable a left join Recent 
    on group_name = a.group_name
```

Comment: This worked, but it only returned the groups that had a review date.  I still needed the full group list as we also need to identify those that need to be reviewed.  Thank you for your help

Comment: Then change it to a left join, I edited the answer for your need

Answer (score 0):

if you need  the value for max  for all the a.group name  rows the ypu should join the subquery for max date

```
select a.Group_Name, t.max_date 
left join (

select b.Group_Name, Max(b.Request_Review_Date) max_date
from GroupReviews b 
Group By b.Group_Name
) t  on t.Group_Name = a.Group_Name
```